# Recognizing text in a ckeditor in Selenium

Tags: selenium, ckeditor

I am trying to do Selenium testing on my app but my app has a ckeditor. Selenium does not recognize text in ckeditor.

My app is on the grails framework.

Can anyone tell me the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well I have not automated ckeditor, but just access demo ckeditor in there site. I think it is pretty much automable. Install Firebug and FirePath. With them you can inspect the element present in the ckeditor. I tried and able to inspect the element using firebug. Use firepath to get the xpath for ckeditor elements. And perform selenium action with these xpaths.